# Помогите деобфусцировать windows bat файл

Tags: bat

Имеется зашифрованный батник, предположительно знаю каким скриптом. Есть ли возможность его расшифровать? Если да, направьте пожалуйста в нужном направлении. Всем спасибо за помощь!(Код опубликовал на pastebin)
[Обфускатор](https://github.com/SkyEmie/batch-obfuscator)

[Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/JfkShvem)